# Bootstrap 2.2.1 Tabbable tabs not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

i'm using bootstrap 2.2.1 and the "tabbable tabs" option doesn't seem to work. Even if i use their own template (for example, the simple "starter template" with the fixed-top navbar) and paste their own tabbable code into my html, they don't respond. The tabs render fine in the page, they're just unresponsive. The code worked for me in an older version of bootstrap--in fact the code for the new website is nearly identical. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

here's the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>N.C</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }

      .container {
        width: auto;
        max-width: 800px;
      }

      .nhc {
        font-family: lucida sans;
        font-color: white;
      }


      #footer {
        text-align: right;

        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-top-color: #990000;
      }

    </style>

    <style type="text/css">

    #footer {
      color: #c4c1ba;
    }

    </style>


    <link href="bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
          <div class="nhc">
          <h1>N.C</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in                    desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

          <div class="container" id="footer">
            <h4>NC</h4>
            <div id="footer">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <img src="mirror.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you including the proper JS? Any JS errors?

Comment: Not that I can tell... I've hardly changed the original html code, let alone the css/js (i'm a total greenhorn here). The links point to the correct folder location, the folder contains all the required css and js, as well as the latest jquery. And i've worked this SIMPLE thing before-- that's why i'm so stumped.

Comment: Ok-- it seems NONE of the components work-- i tried the "collapse" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these two lines in your code..

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
```

Comment: Those links exist in my code already :/ I just added the html to my original question, above.

Comment: just try to add <script src="bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> because i was in a same problem but when I added this JS problem was solved..

Comment: ok, Rupesh-- i did what you said as well as a bunch of other things... and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: hey kartik if my answer is useful to u...don't forget to click on up arrow of my Answer.

Comment: I also downloaded the bootstrap bundle again from the "customize" page and re-pasted the files..